# Are Dungeon Defenders saves cross-platform?

Tags: ios, dungeon-defenders

I just bought Dungeon Defenders on PC, and its ridiculously awesome, so I'm considering buying it on iOS as well. Is there any way I would be able to transfer my heroes from the PC version to the iOS version, and back again?

My iPod is jailbroken and I know how to access its filesystem, so its mostly a matter of what to copy where, and whether or not they're compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ):

> The PC, PS3 and mobile device can share character save files. XBOX 360 will not support this.

So yes, you can just move your local save files over.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just need to find the locations to copy them to/from =)

Comment: I actually have the iOS version and the PC version and if they can share files, I do not see how as of yet.. Also seems a bit 'odd' since you can just buy 200,000 mana for $1 on the iOS version.

Comment: @James its not entirely odd, since the port of the characters are only for the 'open' version, and on the ranked trendynet, the option to buy mana isn't available (yet).

Comment: @yx Have you found out how to move the characters around? My PC characters are much more played than my iPad and would not mind them both being the same. I went in and made sure GameCenter was turned off and all but I am still not sure what's next.

Comment: @James, here is a link to the DD wiki that tells you how: http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_backup_iOS